# Moving body to IFRAME spoils the inner links

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I copy the whole HTML to an IFRAME:

```
var h = $('html')[0].outerHTML;
$('body').append('<iframe width="300" height="300" id="someId"></iframe>');
$('#someId').load(function() {
    $('#someId').contents().find('html').html(h);
    alert($('#someId').contents().find('html')[0].outerHTML);
});
```

this works so far, but the images/css, other links gets broken. The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<base href="/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
.
.
.
<img src="/pictures/a.gif" />
```

and so on. This way, it works good both on develop and production server.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Comment: what you want?? you want to move the body content of main page to body of Iframe??

**html -> body -> content**      to     **html -> body -> iframe -> body -> Content**

Comment: yes, its already done, it works. But then the images wont show, links wont work (as they were dead links)

Comment: I tried it and its working.. let me post my code here..

Comment: your links and images are all set relative to your document and as your iframe has no src the browser won't know where to get the links from unless you full qualify them - eg put `http://www.somedomain.com/pictures/a.gif`.  If you are just moving the whole page to the iframe why not use the pages url as the src?

Comment: not solvable everytime (think of a content which can be managed with AJAX, just like gmail)

Answer (score 1):

I tried and its working in my case check it out..!!!

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- jquery file path-->
    <script src="blog/jquery.min.js" style="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function(){     
            // get the content of main page body
            var con = $("body").html();

            // replace everything in body and place a Iframe in body
            $('body').html('<iframe width="300" height="300" id="someId"></iframe>');       

            // set the content of the iframe body
            $('#someId').contents().find('body').html(con);     
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>      
    Goole  : <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt = "My Icon" style="height:100px;width:250px"/> 
    Your content goes here..    
</body>
</html>
```